# Playwright retry policy for text appearing

Tags: automated-tests, playwright, retry-logic

I have a use case for needing to reload a page until some text is populated on a page.  I'm new to both Playwright and Javascript and am trying to find a good pattern for doing this.

My current method uses the `async-retry` library:

```
 const customerName = await this.page.locator(this.elements.customerName);
 const expectedCustomerName = 'Dave'
  
  async checkCustomerNameRetry() {
    try {
      await retry(
        async () => {
          await this.page.reload();
          await customerName.waitFor({state: 'visible'});
          await expect(customerName).toContainText(expectedCustomerName);
        }, {retries: 10, factor: 1, minTimeout: 1000, maxTimeout: 5000}
      );
    } catch (Error) {
      logger.log(`Could not find customer name after 10 retries`);
    }
  }
```

This seems sub-optimal - not least because of the unnecessary page.reload() even before the first check. I wonder if there's a better utility method I could use using plain Playwright api?

Comment: Is there a problem with a loop, possibly a delay, and `page.reload()`? I don't understand why a third party library is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They implemented an expect.poll for this sort of scenario: https://playwright.dev/docs/testing-library#replacing-waitfor

The whole statement must complete with the expected result, or Playwright will retry it until success or timeout. In your case, it'd be something like (sorry, typing this directly in the response box, so please forgive any typos or syntax errors):

```
await expect.poll(async () => {
  await this.page.reload();
  await customerName.waitFor({state: 'visible'});
  return customerName;
}).toBe(expectedCustomerName);
```

Comment: There’s [polling](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#polling) as shown as well as [retrying](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#retrying) that basically would do what their current third party retry does. Also, if you want to avoid that first reload, you could have an index variable initialized outside the retry block that you increment inside and check to see if first/0 before reloading.